How to make the background behind a presented sheet view decrease in opacity as the user pulls the sheet down?
I would like it so as I pull the sheet down, the opacity of the background behind the sheet will decrease / become more transparent. Originally this wouldnt have been a problem because apple's built-in sheet dims the background a bit and decreases opacity as you pull the sheet down. But the background dim wasnt enough for my preference. So I added a darker dimmed background behind the sheet and now my custom made one doesnt have the same effect as the apple default one.
Example of the background behind the sheet not decreasing in opaciy as i drag the sheet down:
https://i.sstatic.net/iVu8mvuj.gif
Here's my code:
How i made the background darker:
//ContentView
@State private var showFocusOptions: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    //Views behind the dim background...

    Color.black.opacity(showFocusOptions ? 0.3 : 0)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: showFocusOptions)
}

The sheet (the button is the pill shape labeled "Focus" in the gif):
//TimerView
@Binding var showFocusOptions: Bool
@State private var selectedFocus = "Focus"

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        showFocusOptions = true
        provideHapticFeedback(style: .light)
    }) {
        Text(selectedFocus)
            .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .padding(20)
            .frame(maxWidth: 180, maxHeight: 42)
            .background(Color.lightmango)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(30)
    }
    .padding(.top, -70)
    .sheet(isPresented: $showFocusOptions) {
        FocusOptionsView(selectedFocus: $selectedFocus)
            .presentationDetents([.height(370), .fraction(0.999)])
            .presentationBackground(.white)
            .presentationCornerRadius(45)
    }
}

